Percentiles of multiple samples
I am looking for a way to calculate percentiles for a set of variables from multiple samples from unknown distributions, where each sample consists of the same set of variables whose sum is always 1.
The example should make it clear exactly what I mean:
Sample 1 consists of $x_{1, 1} ... x_{1,n}$, sample $k$ consists of $x_{k,1} ... x_{k,n}$, until sample $K$ consists of $x_{K,1} ... x_{K,n}$. The sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{k,i}$ is always 1 for each $k$ and each $x_{k,n} \in [0,1]$.
The different percentiles of the set $x_{k, n=n'} \forall k$ with fixed $n'$ is not a problem, but is there a reasonable way to specify percentiles for the samples? For example, in such a way that the 0.2 percentile of $x_{k,1} = 0.35$ and the 0.2 percentile of $x_{k,2} = 0.80$ and normalizing these back to 1 to get a form of lower (or upper) bound for the samples or would this be pointless nonsense?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
